# Issue:How to track Event as a goal with no thank you page or conversion page?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have this scenario where I dont have thank you page or conversion page for my products.
There is only small massage shows after form filling.
So how can I track this event as a goal in my analytics?

Any suggestion with google tag manager or without it would be good.
So please help me with it.

```
    <!--inquiry form starts-->
<div class="inquiry_popup" id="inquiry_owner_popup"  style="display:none;">
  <div class="signin_signup_popup_head">
    <div class="send_an_inquiry">Let us know what you need.</div>
    <div class="inquiry_owner_popup_close rightF">X</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="text_blue">We will have the perfect venue owners contact you back.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inquiry_frm" id="inquiry_frm">
    <div class="signup_form_error"></div>
    <form id="inquiry_owner_form" method="post" >
      <div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="success_msg"></div>
      <div>
        <div class="pull_left inquiry_form_style">
          <label class="inquiry_text"> NAME </label>
          <input name="name" class="inquiry_field" type="text" value="" />
          <label class="inquiry_text"> EMAIL ADDRESS </label>
          <input name="email" class="inquiry_field email" type="text" value="" />
          <label class="inquiry_text"> MOBILE NUMBER </label>
          <input name="mobile" class="inquiry_field" type="text" />
          <label class="inquiry_text"> NUMBER OF GUESTS </label>
          <input name="noofguestes" class="inquiry_field" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="pull_left inquiry_form_style">
          <label class="inquiry_text"> EVENT DATE </label>
          <input name="event_owner_date" id="event_owner_date" class="inquiry_field" type="text" />
          <label class="inquiry_text top_33">
            <input type="checkbox" name="flex" value="1" />
            My dates are flexible </label>
          <label class="inquiry_text top_25"> ADDITIONAL COMMENTS </label>
          <textarea name="comments" class="inquiry_field height_95" > </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="submit" class="inquiry_btn_field top_20" id="signup_button" name="signup_button" value="Send" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!--inquiry form ends-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of ways of doing it, based on your description the way I would do it with GTM is like the following:

Create an event on GTM that listens to events that are pushed via the data layer. On how to do this, go to this post: http://moz.com/ugc/tracking-google-analytics-events-with-google-tag-manager Start with "Tracking Google Analytics Events with GTM: The Second Way" and do steps: 1,2 and 3.

Then, run javascript code that is executed when the thank you messaging appears. This will make sure that you will record the event upon a successful conversion. (this code will make sense after you've finished the tutorial above.)

```
dataLayer.push({ 'event':'GAevent', 'eventCategory':'Conversion123', 'eventAction':'YOUR DATA', 'eventLabel':YOUR DATA});
```

Finally, create a goal in Google Analytics based on an event:
[image: event as goal]

Now your event will be counted as goals. But remember that goal, unlike event, can be carried out only one time in a session, unlike events, which can be recorded couple of times during a session. So if the user filled in the form twice with the same event values in one session, you will have 2 events, but 1 goal completion.

Comment: Whole website use ajax to show data and the conversion massage on form. will it work?

Comment: I don't see a reason why it won't work on AJAX. Make sure that the JS code of the dataLayer push runs on the same domain as your GA web property.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use GTM, I'd suggest you add a onclick to the submit button and send an event through to Google Analytics. You'd then set up a goal conversion once GA see the event.

For the Classic version of Analytics (ga.js), you'd use something like this on the button you want to track as an event:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label']);" />
```

So full example would be:

```
<input type="submit" class="inquiry_btn_field top_20" id="signup_button" name="signup_button" value="Send" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label']);" />
```

You would then need to set up your goal to the same name as you put into category, action and label.

If you use Universal Analytics (analytics.js) you'd use something like this:

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event','category','action','label');
```

Full example would be something like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="inquiry_btn_field top_20" id="signup_button" name="signup_button" value="Send" onClick="ga('send', 'event','category','action','label');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Virtual Page View in Google Analytics. This allows a user to track a goal even if there is no destination page and works on the interaction of the user.
You can paste this piece of code on the interaction area which you want to track on clicking.

onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageView', 'Name']);"

You can even Create Funnels with this virtual page views.

1. Open Google Analytics Account
2. Click Admin
3. Choose Goals in the View level
4. Click New Goal
5. Click on Destination, choosing destination you have 2 options where you can place the URL or the Name that you have mentioned in the Code

For Reference Visit https://blog.kissmetrics.com/ga-virtual-pageviews/